# How to store arrays in strings.xml or assets and use in ListViewAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I want to create more than 1500 LyricsFullDetail in the ListViewAdapter, but my problem is i don't want to hardcode the Lyrics Full Detail in the the ListViewAdapter.java. I want to store the lyrics full detail and read from Strings.xml or assets folder. The music files are saved in the raw folder.
I will so much appreciate if you help me with an example fix.thanks Below are my codes.

**This is the itemClick codes i repeated into 1500 times which gave me 'code too large error'**

***That is why I'm struggling to save it somewhere like assets folder and read in ListViewAdapter***

```js
 //listview item clicks
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //code later
                if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 001 | This song lyrics 1")) {
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 001");
                    intent.putExtra("position", 1);
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "1. O THOU to whose all-searching sight\n" +
                            "The darkness shineth as the light,\n" +
                            "Search, prove my heart, it pants for thee;\n" +
                            "O burst these bonds and set it free!\n" +
                            "\n" +
                            "2. Wash out its stain, refine its dross,\n" +
                            "Nail my affections to the cross:\n" +
                            "Hallow each thought, let all within\n" +
                            "Be clean, as thou, my Lord, art clean.");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 002 | This song lyrics 2")) {
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("position", 2);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 002");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "3 Saviour, where’er thy steps I see,\n" +
                            "Dauntless, untired, I’ll follow thee;\n" +
                            "O let thy hand support me still\n" +
                            "And lead me to thy holy hill!\n" +
                            "\n" +
                            "4 If rough and thorny be the way,\n" +
                            "My strength proportion to my day,\n" +
                            "Till toil and grief and pain shall cease,\n" +
                            "Where all is calm and joy and peace.");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 003 | This song lyrics 3")) {
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("position", 3);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 003");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "1. O THOU to whose all-searching sight\n" +
                            "The darkness shineth as the light,\n" +
                            "Search, prove my heart, it pants for thee;\n" +
                            "O burst these bonds and set it free!\n" +
                            "\n" +
                            "2. Wash out its stain, refine its dross,\n" +
                            "Nail my affections to the cross:\n" +
                            "Hallow each thought, let all within\n" +
                            "Be clean, as thou, my Lord, art clean.");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 004 | This song lyrics 4")) {
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("position", 4);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 004");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is song lyrics detail\n\n\n\n");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 005 | This song lyrics 5")) {
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("position", 5);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 005");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is song lyrics detail");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 006 | This song lyrics 6")) {
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("position", 6);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 006");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is song lyrics detail");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 007 | This song lyrics 7")) {
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("position", 7);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 007");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is song lyrics detail");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });


        return view;
    }
```

**This is the ListViewAdapter.java**

```js
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    //Variables
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Model> modellist;
    ArrayList<Model> arrayList;
    int[] soundfile;

    //Constructor
    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<Model> modellist) {
        mContext = context;
        this.modellist = modellist;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.arrayList = new ArrayList<Model>();
        this.arrayList.addAll(modellist);
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView mTitleTv, mDescTv;
        ImageView mIconTv, favorite;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return modellist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return modellist.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

            //locate the views in row.xml
            holder.mTitleTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mainTitle);
            holder.mDescTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mainDesc);
            holder.mIconTv = view.findViewById(R.id.mainIcon);
            //initialize the favorite image view
            holder.favorite = view.findViewById(R.id.favorite);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        //set the result into textview
        holder.mTitleTv.setText(modellist.get(i).getTitle());
        holder.mDescTv.setText(modellist.get(i).getDesc());
        //Set the result in imagview
        holder.mIconTv.setImageResource(modellist.get(i).getIcon());

        if (modellist.get(i).isFavorite())
            holder.favorite.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_heart));
        else
            holder.favorite.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_heart_o));

        //listview soundfile file for songs in position
        soundfile = new int[]{R.raw.song_1, R.raw.song_2, R.raw.song_3, R.raw.song_4, R.raw.song_5, R.raw.song_6, R.raw.song_7, R.raw.song_8,};

        //fovarite/unfavorite

        holder.favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (modellist.get(i).isFavorite())
                    holder.favorite.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_heart_o));
                else
                    holder.favorite.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_heart));

                modellist.get(i).setFavorite();
            }
        });

        //listview item clicks
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //code later
                if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 001 | This song lyrics 1")) {
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 001");
                    intent.putExtra("position", 1);
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "1. O THOU to whose all-searching sight\n" +
                            "The darkness shineth as the light,\n" +
                            "Search, prove my heart, it pants for thee;\n" +
                            "O burst these bonds and set it free!\n" +
                            "\n" +
                            "2. Wash out its stain, refine its dross,\n" +
                            "Nail my affections to the cross:\n" +
                            "Hallow each thought, let all within\n" +
                            "Be clean, as thou, my Lord, art clean.\n\n\n\n");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 002 | This song lyrics 2")) {
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("position", 2);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 002");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "3 Saviour, where’er thy steps I see,\n" +
                            "Dauntless, untired, I’ll follow thee;\n" +
                            "O let thy hand support me still\n" +
                            "And lead me to thy holy hill!\n" +
                            "\n" +
                            "4 If rough and thorny be the way,\n" +
                            "My strength proportion to my day,\n" +
                            "Till toil and grief and pain shall cease,\n" +
                            "Where all is calm and joy and peace.\n\n\n\n");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 003 | This song lyrics 3")) {
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("position", 3);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 003");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "1. O THOU to whose all-searching sight\n" +
                            "The darkness shineth as the light,\n" +
                            "Search, prove my heart, it pants for thee;\n" +
                            "O burst these bonds and set it free!\n" +
                            "\n" +
                            "2. Wash out its stain, refine its dross,\n" +
                            "Nail my affections to the cross:\n" +
                            "Hallow each thought, let all within\n" +
                            "Be clean, as thou, my Lord, art clean.\n\n\n\n");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 004 | This song lyrics 4")) {
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("position", 4);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 004");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is song lyrics detail\n\n\n\n");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 005 | This song lyrics 5")) {
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("position", 5);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 005");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is song lyrics detail\n\n\n\n");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 006 | This song lyrics 6")) {
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("position", 6);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 006");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is song lyrics detail\n\n\n\n");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 007 | This song lyrics 7")) {
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("position", 7);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 007");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is song lyrics detail\n\n\n\n");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    //filter
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        modellist.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            modellist.addAll(arrayList);
        } else {
            for (Model model : arrayList) {
                if (model.getTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                    modellist.add(model);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}
```

**This is the MainActivity.java where i saved the list arrays**

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    private String TAG = "MainActivity ----- ; " ;
    // Store instance variables

    private int page;
    private ConsentForm form;

    ListView listView;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    String[] title;
    String[] description;
    int[] icon;
    ArrayList<Model> arrayList = new ArrayList<Model>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //initialize preferences
        PreferenceUtils.initialize(getApplicationContext());

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Redeemed Songs");

        title = new String[]{"Song 001 | This song lyrics 1","Song 002 | This song lyrics 2","Song 003 | This song lyrics 3","Song 004 | This song lyrics 4","Song 005 | This song lyrics 5","Song 006 | This song lyrics 6","Song 007 | This song lyrics 7"};

        description = new String[]{"MORNING song", "MORNING song", "MORNING song", "MORNING song", "MORNING song", "MORNING song", "MORNING song",};

        icon = new int[]{ R.drawable.song, R.drawable.song, R.drawable.song, R.drawable.song,R.drawable.song,R.drawable.song, R.drawable.song,};

        listView = findViewById(R.id.list);

        for (int i =0; i<title.length; i++){
            Model model =new Model(title[i], description[i], icon[i]);
            //let's simply say, the song identifier is just the order of the song in the list
            model.id = i;
            //bind all strings in an array
            arrayList.add(model);
        }

        //pass result to listview class
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, arrayList);

        //bind the adapter to the listview class
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView)myActionMenuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s)){
                    adapter.filter("");
                    listView.clearTextFilter();
                }
                else {
                    adapter.filter(s);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id==R.id.action_settings){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Settings Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class));
            return true;
            //do your funtionality here

        }
        else if (id==R.id.action_howtouse){
                Toast.makeText(this, "How-To", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, FavoriteListActivity.class));
            return true;
                //do your funtionality here


        }else if (id==R.id.action_favorites){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Favorites Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, FavoriteListActivity.class));
            return true;
                //do your funtionality here


        }
        else if (id==R.id.action_developers){
            Toast.makeText(this, "About", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Main4Activity.class));
            return true;
            //do your funtionality here

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a List from and String Array in the strings.xml this can then be then be used in and Adapter, you could have a parallel array to match the Song title to Lyrics

But you are probably better using an SQLite database for this type of stuff either directly or Using Android Rooms.

Training material for rooms (which is a layer on top of SQLite) https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/

or more direct https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite.html

```java
List<String> myLyricList = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_lyrics));

List<String> myTitleList = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_titles));
```

strings.xml

```xml
<string-array name="array_lyrics">
        <item>This song lyrics 1</item>
        <item>This song lyrics 2</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="array_titles">
        <item>Song 001</item>
        <item>Song 002</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: how I'm i going to set the intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 002");

Comment: Can you help fix with my code as example? Thanks you

Comment: Ok i think i should go for SQLite database for this type of ListView. Please can you help me with a video tutorial link or maybe source code from github. I don't know how to use SQLite. Please sir i have this project to present on Monday. Please help me. I can pay for help